# Accepting Multiple Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are time when I ask a question and receive multiple answers. There have been many cases where the answers provided are outstanding and I would like to give credit to multiple answers with more than an up vote.

For instance I accept the best answer as my accepted answer. But I also have the option of marking another answer as a great answer or with some sort of acknowledgment. When awarded you receive +10 reputation vs the +15 of an answer and you are limited in how many you can award. (Say no more than 2 per question or possibly even 1).

This lets other users know "This answer has merit as well as the accepted answer."

As far as I am aware no other SE site does this yet it would be nice to see implemented.

Comment: You could give a bounty.

Comment: @mattdm - That is an idea but one issue, the minimum bounty is 50 points. What I am thinking is a little less than that.

Comment: Maybe the thing to do is allow smaller "hey, thanks!" bounties.

Comment: @mattdm Accepting the answer gives 15 points, so the thanks bounty can also be set to 15 points. ;)

Comment: @mattdm - That sounds like a perfect solution. I would like to see the "Hey Thanks" bounties to range from 10 - 25 points.

Comment: You can (and should) vote up other answers that have merit - there are even badges awarded when a non-accepted answer beats the accepted one, IIRC.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - I always up vote answers that I think have merit. I would like to at time give more credit than an up vote. (But less than a 50 bounty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This lets other users know "This answer has merit as well as the accepted answer."

There is already provision for this:

1. Click the upvote arrow next to each of the answers that you found helpful. Each upvote gives the author +10 rep.
2. If you feel one of the answers was *especially* awesome, start a bounty and award it to the answer. This can be done an unlimited number of times, although the starting bounty amount does increase for each subsequent bounty.

I don't feel adding more complexity to the accepted answer mechanism is warranted, given the above.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why it would make sense to have something between 10 and 50, which is essentially what you are requesting. You already provide the 10 with the vote up, and you have the option to award 50+ using the bounty. If the answer was especially good but not selected as the accepted answer, the community will surely trend towards awarding upvotes and thus more rep.

I think you Lynda are somewhat of an atypical user here, in that you are quite active but have a somewhat small amount of rep. I think users with 500 rep or similar like you have, are less likely to be concerned with awarding multiple answers more rep. Extending this idea, users with more rep, aren't going to be concerned with giving up 50+ for a bounty for the most part.

Comment: And @Lynda: after a while you'll have lots of rep to burn. It just takes a little while but once you've asked and answered a bunch of questions it starts going up exponentially.

Comment: @dpolitt - You are correct about your observation. =>